# In MediaWiki templates how to show empty default value

Tags: mediawiki, template

In a MediaWiki template I'm making, I want to let it to become `[[CODE-value]]` when `CODE=value` is used and empty when `CODE=value` is not given in the actual page.   The current version

```
[[CODE-{{{CODE|}}}|{{{CODE|}}}]]
```

fails the second requirement.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [`{{#if}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23if).

Comment: Using `{{#if: {{{CODE}}} | [[CODE-{{{CODE}}}]] | (not applicable) }}` in the template still does not work.  Any additional hint?

Comment: I think you need `{{#if: {{{CODE|}}}`, so that the condition is empty when `CODE` is not set.

Comment: That didn't work.  I'm using this code in a template.  That's probably problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) extension is installed.

Then put the following in a template, such as `Template:Iftest`

```
{{#if: {{{CODE|}}} | [[CODE-{{{CODE}}}]] | (not applicable) }}
```

If CODE-parameter is empty or not present you get `(not applicable)`. i.e.

- `{{Iftest|CODE=123}}` gives `[[CODE-123]]`
- `{{Iftest|CODE=}}` gives `(not applicable)`
- `{{Iftest}}` gives `(not applicable)`

Comment: This does not work in a template.

Comment: How are you calling your template and passing it the value of `CODE`?

Comment: Yes, I put the code you showed into a template, and created a new page applying the template with some value assigned to parameter `CODE`.  It does not show desired output.

Comment: That is odd. Have you got a link to the live example of your template?

Comment: Ah. Looks like that wiki doesn't have the [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) extension installed. That extension is required for `#if` to work.

Comment: Added the examples and the need for ParsedFunctions to the answer